# ¿Cómo realizar cambios de forma inmediata usando MEAN stack?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, mongodb, express

**Problemática**

Hola! Estoy queriendo realizar un botón de (Like) o me gusta como se lo conoce habitualmente para una red social, ya tengo las funciones y servicios para que el usuario que haya iniciado sesión pueda dar like y quitarlo, estos cambios se guardan en la base de datos y dispongo de un botón con un contador de los likes almacenados de una publicación, todo va bien al momento de agregar y quitar los like al momento de hacer click en el botón pero se demora y los cambios son asíncrónicos del contador, por ello yo quiero que se realicen los cambios de forma automática sin tener que llamar de nuevo a la función de (contarReacciones())

**Ejemplo**

El usuario registrado ingresa a una publicación y quiere dar like pero se demora al momento de ejecutar las funciones de (darLike()---Ingresa el like del usuario y de la publicación en la base de datos ) y (contarReacciones() ---Muestra el contador de reacciones tanto de los likes, comentarios y compartidas de la publicación, se Almacena correctamente el like en la base de datos pero hasta ejecutar el de contarReacciones() pasa por lo menos 2 segundos hasta que ejecute ambas funciones, por lo que quiero que los cambios se vean reflejados de forma inmediata.

**publicacion.components.ts**

Función que me permite obtener los valores de Like, comentarios y compartidas de la publicación

```
contarReacciones() {
    if (this.id != null) {
      this._reaccionesService.obtenerReacciones(this.id).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          if (data.likes != 0) {
            this.cont_likes = data.likes;
          } else {
            this.cont_likes = '';
          }

          if (data.comentarios != 0) {
            this.cont_comentarios = data.comentarios;
          } else {
            this.cont_comentarios = '';
          }

          if (data.compartidas != 0) {
            this.cont_compartidas = data.compartidas;
          } else {
            this.cont_compartidas = '';
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Función que me permite verificar si el usuario registrado ha dado ya like en la publicación, si es verdadero entonces lo elimina, caso contrario lo crea.

```
verificarLike() {
    var usuario = localStorage.getItem('id');
    if (usuario != null && this.id != null) {
      this._reaccionesService.verificarLike(this.id,usuario).subscribe(
        (data) => {
         try {
          this.id_like = data[0]._id;
          this.eliminarLike();
         } catch (error) {
          console.log('No existe');
          this.darLike();
         }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    } else{
      console.log('Porfavor inicie sesión')
    }
    
  }
```

Función que me guarda el Like en la base de datos

```
darLike() {
    var usuario = localStorage.getItem('id');
    if(this.id_like != ""){
      if (usuario != null && this.id != null) {
        const LIKES: Likes = {
          id_publicacion: this.id,
          id_usuario: usuario,
          fecha: this.fecha,
        };
        this._reaccionesService.agregarLike(LIKES).subscribe(
          (data) => {
            this.cambiarAspectoLike();
          this.contarReacciones(); 
            this.id_like = data._id;
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
      } else {
        console.log('Inicia sesión!');
      }
    }else{
        this.eliminarLike();
    }
    
  }
```

Función que me permite eliminar el like en el caso que ya lo haya dado

```
 eliminarLike(){
    if(this.id_like !=null){
      this._reaccionesService.eliminarLikes(this.id_like).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.contarReacciones(); 
          this.defaultAspectoLike();
        },
        (error) =>{
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
    }
      
    

  }
```

**Servicios  (likes.service.ts)**

```
    import { Injectable ,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable, ObservableLike } from 'rxjs';
    import { Likes } from '../models/likes';
    
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ReaccionesService {
      cambio = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
      url = 'http://localhost:4000/api/reacciones/'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  agregarLike(likes:Likes): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(this.url,likes);
  } 

  obtenerReacciones(id: string):Observable<any>{
    this.cambio.emit(true);
    return this.http.get(this.url + id);
  }

  verificarLike(id_publicacion: string, id_usuario:string): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get(this.url +id_publicacion + '/' + id_usuario )
  }

  eliminarLikes(id: string): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.delete(this.url + id);
  }
 
/*  editarLikes(id:string,usuario: string):Observable<any>{
      return this.http.put(this.url + id,usuario);
  } */
 

}
```

Estaba queriendo implementar el emitter pero soy nuevo en esto y no sé como me pueda funcionar.

Comment: Bienvenido Michael, creo que tú pregunta puede ser demasiado amplia para una respuesta... Te recomendaría que buscaras acerca de "Optimistic Updates"

Comment: muchas gracias @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, estaba buscando información pero no hay mucha, me podrías ayudar con un blog o web de referencia.

Comment: La acción del front no tiene porqué estar atada a la del back. Haces like y actualizas localmente la vista, para el usuario es inmediato, la acción de like viaja al back por detrás sin que el usuario se de por enterado. Sólo si la acción en el back falla, alertas al usuario y reviertes la vista. Lo que te está fallando es la lógica de implementación. Saludos

Comment: Si, @MauricioContreras estás en lo correcto, el método que estaba aplicando creaba varias peticiones para dar like, eliminar por lo que no es óptimo, lo arreglé cambiando todo a una sola petición hacia el servidor pasando parámetros necesarios para lo que necesito, muchas gracias